# Is there a database where one can find the Electron Density data of materials?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, databases, machine-learning, materials-informatics

The database I am looking for may be ***experimental, computational or user-generated data***. If I end up using the data, I will be providing the necessary citations and credits. Thank You.

Comment: +1; it would be nice to know if such a database exist. but its quite unlikely due to the size of cube files. but you could always calculate the electron density yourself. its just an SCF calculation followed by some post processing in Quantum ESPRESSO

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. How do you automate the scf calculation (data generation) for thousands of molecules? I would like to discuss this stuff with you further! Sent you an email :)

Comment: if you have access to cif files of those molecules, you could use the cif2cell command line too automate the task of creating input files from those cif files; then with some python code I believe you could pull this off

Comment: Have you thought through the necessary hardware capacity of your needs? It is easy to generate a bunch a cube files, but you may run out of storage space if you just playing around with 1000s of those.

Comment: @Greg wouldn't a cluster support the same for generating 1000s of those?

Comment: @PranoyRay I am not sure what you would like to ask. All I am saying that if you want to generate high-resolution cube files, be careful with the storage. Of course, everything depends on how high resolution you need and how big molecules.

Comment: You might want to check out the materials project. They have a computational database. See for instance, [cubic diamond silicon](https://www.materialsproject.org/materials/mp-149/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently made charge densities available for the MOFs and coordination polymers of the Quantum MOF (QMOF) Database. Please read [the GitHub page](https://github.com/arosen93/QMOF) for details on how to access the charge densities. That being said, given the large size of the files, I wish you luck downloading it in bulk.

Comment: 404 error on that GitHub page.

Comment: Seems like you embedded the link partially wrong. I corrected the answer for you and I was able to access the data. How big is the total data you have available, sizewise? I am planning to take a precautionary measure on my storage options before downloading.

Comment: Thanks for catching/fixing the 404 error. I think it should be roughly on the order of ~750 GB.

Comment: Do you know what associated properties (physical/electronic/mechanical) are available with the charge density files? @AndrewRosen

Comment: @PranoyRay -- You can find the details you request [here](http://materialsproject.org/mofs). Please see the documentation tab for more details.